# C# - Using loop to open dialog box

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, dialog

I'm trying to make a program that loads a configuration file from another application.
If the file exists, it loads it and displays a message, but if the configuration file is not valid, it displays an error message and then opens a dialog box to load the correct file. But if the user reloads the wrong file, the same dialog box should appear again but that's when my code fails.

Similarly, if the file did not exist from the beginning, it displays a dialog box to load the file, but if it is given to cancel the dialog box or an incorrect file is selected again, my code fails.

I know that the solution would be to use loops but I'm not sure how to structure it.
Pd: searchfile() is my function to open dialog box and readconfig() is my function to read config file of another application.

```
    strfilenamepath = @"C:\Users\test\dogs.exe.config";

    if (File.Exists(strfilenamepath))
    {
        onlyFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strfilenamepath);
        textBox1.Text = onlyFilename;
        try
        {
            string[] valores = readConfig(strfilenamepath);
            MessageBox.Show(valores[0] + valores[1] + valores[2]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading config file." + ex.Message);
            searchFile();
            onlyFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strfilenamepath);
            textBox1.Text = onlyFilename;
            string[] valores = readConfig(strfilenamepath);
            MessageBox.Show(valores[0] + valores[1] + valores[2]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        searchFile();
        onlyFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strfilenamepath);
        textBox1.Text = onlyFilename;
        try
        {
            readConfig(strfilenamepath);
            string[] valores = readConfig(strfilenamepath);
            MessageBox.Show(valores[0] + valores[1] + valores[2]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading config file." + ex.Message);
            searchFile();
            onlyFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strfilenamepath);
            textBox1.Text = onlyFilename;
            string[] valores = readConfig(strfilenamepath);
            MessageBox.Show(valores[0] + valores[1] + valores[2]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the loop? What is `searchFile()`?

Comment: I had not use the loop because I dont know how to structure it in my code. Searchfile() is only a simole function that open a dialog box and save the path in a variable.

Comment: You don't want a loop.  Just post your message to the user that it wasn't valid and make the user click the button to try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to design it if you extract the reading logic to another method that handles exceptions and returns a Boolean to signal the success and the computed result. The `TryDoSomething` pattern does exactly this.

In pseudo code

```
public bool TryReadConfig(string path, out string[] valores)
{
    valores = null;
    try {
        valores = read the values;
        return true;
    } catch {
        Display message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The main loop in pseudo code

```
strfilenamepath = @"C:\Users\test\dogs.exe.config";

while (true) {
    if (File.Exists(strfilenamepath) && TryReadConfig(strfilenamepath, out var valores)) {
        Do something with the valores;
        break;
    }
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog{ ... };
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        strfilenamepath = ofd.Filename;
    } else {
        break; // The user canceled the operation.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
try
{
    //Code to try open the file to memory
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    while (true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Select an valid file");

        var path = searchFile();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            continue;

        try
        {
            //Code to try open the file to memory
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"The selected file is not valid");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```